# C++ stack based constructor/destructor not working as expected

Tags: c++

I have trouble understanding why the following code doesn't construct and destruct the two objects I create the way I'd expect:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {

    int myVar;

public:
    MyClass(int x) {
        myVar = x;
        std::cout << "constructing " << myVar << ", " << (long)this << std::endl;
    }

    ~MyClass() {
        std::cout << "destructing " << myVar << ", " << (long)this << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    MyClass a = MyClass(1);
    a = MyClass(2);
    return 0;
}
```

I'd think that inside main I first create an object with the value 1, then create a new one with value 2. And each of the objects gets constructed and destructed, so that I'd expect to see the following output:

```
constructing 1, 3456
constructing 2, 6789
destructing 1, 3456
destructing 2, 6789
```

However, I get this:

```
constructing 1, 3456
constructing 2, 6789
destructing 2, 6789   <- note the "2"
destructing 2, 3456
```

**Update: I've added output of the object's address (*this*) so that one can better see which object does what.**

When I use "new MyClass" instead, I do not run into this weird effect.

What is causing this, and, understanding my goal, what is the right way to avoid similar mistakes in the future?

While this example looks harmless, I ran into crashes of my code because I had allocated other objects in the constructor and freed them in the destructor. This did lead to freeing the objects when the object was still in use.

**Conclusion**

Now that all my questions are answered, let me summarize:

1. In the above example I'm using "myVar", which doesn't show even the issue that caused me to bring up this question. My apologies for that.
2. The actual issue I had with the code is that I was not using a simple int var but an array that I created with "new" in the destructor, and freed with delete in the destructor. And with that, the array would get deleted twice, leading to incorrect data in my program.
3. The fix is to not use a simple pointer to the array but a reference counting pointer, so that, when it gets copied by the assignment operator, it increases the refcount, thereby preventing premature release of it.
4. In general, the effect I've shown here is nothing dangerous - it doesn't damage anything as I had gotten the impression. The dangerous part was that I didn't use ref counting ptrs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question was answered, but I think I should explain why author's real project crashes.
We have some class, that contains some object, this object is created in constructor and deleted in destructor:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public:
        SomeClass(int param) { mObject = new SomeObj(param); }
        ~SomeClass() { delete mObject; }
    private:
        SomeObj * mObject;
}
```

When we're doing something like

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    SomeClass a = SomeClass(1);//1
    a = SomeClass(2);//2
    return 0;//3
}
```

We're calling SomeObj constructor on line 1, then on line2. After that we're calling 
`SomeClass::operator=(SomeClass& rhs)`,
which is autogenerated for us, its body is just 
`{ mObject = rhs.mObject; }`
So what we see?

```
object1.mObject = object2.mObject;
//old object1.mObject is leaked now, we have no pointer to it.
delete object2; // it was temporary, its lifetime is just one line of code
//it calls
delete object2.mObject; // it equals to delete object1.mObject, because both pointers point to same object
delete object1;//after end of main()
//it calls
delete object1.mObject; // ERROR! object was deleted
```

So it's nothing wrong with c++ ;)

Comment: Kudos for showing the actual issue with the object I had been allocating. I'm torn between your and @phonetagger's answer because each of them explains part of the issue pretty well. Yours is still lacking the clarity that phonetagger's has.

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann, I like phonetagger's answer, it fully explains the issue, I wrote my answer just because didn't managed to explain issue with pointers in comments to JonathanWakely's answer

Answer (score 11):

The line `a = MyClass(2);` will not call a destructor, it will call the assignment operator  (`MyClass::operator=`) which you have not implemented, so the compiler provides one for you - it doesn't "print" anything, so you don't see that.

The reason you get `destrucing 2` twice is that immediately after the line `a = MyClass(2);`, the temporary `MyClass(2)` object is destroyed. Then at the end of `main` the variable `a` is destroyed, and since `myVar` is now 2, it prints 2 again.

Comment: Som how do I prevent this unwanted effect from happening? I.e, I do not want the compiler to issue an assignment operator silently that enables this unexpected behavior.

Comment: You may implement your own assignment operator if you wish.

Comment: So you're saying that to avoid this issue, I'll have to add my own assignment operator to any class I write? That can't be the solution

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann: Fortunately it's very rare not to want assignment, so all in all you are generally thankful for this behavior :)

Comment: I've updated my example. The issue is that I allocate objects in the constructor which I free in the destructor. This leads to crashes with the above code because I end up freeing the wrong objects in the destructor. I'd think this is a common issue and that C++ would somehow better guard from this mistake.

Comment: If I add a private "operator=", then I can't write "a = MyClass(2)" any more. Is there some other way to re-assign a with a new object then, while freeing the old one?

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann write your code differently? If you don't use raw pointers as class members then you won't have this problem. If you absolutely have to deal with pointers then use smart-pointers unless you are writing really low-level code. Otherwise just use the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))

Comment: @PeterT Ahh, now wer're getting somewhere! The issue with deleting the allocations twice in my destructor happens because they get copied but not not ref-counted! If they were ref-counted, it would all be safe. That explains the issue. I see now that I should have included the pointer-deletion issue in the destructor from the beginning, but I had not thougth it being relevant.

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann you don't need them to be ref-counted. If you don't actually share the pointer just use `std::unique_ptr`. You just need them to have value semantics.

Answer (score 3):

```
a = MyClass(2);
```

Uses the copy assignment operator `operator=` provided by the compiler. This is the reason why you see `destructing 2`.

So during the copy, a.myVar get the value `2` instead of `1`.

The temporary object is destroyed after the semicolon of the line :

```
a = MyClass(2);
//             ^- Here
```

And at the end of the block, `a` is also destructed.

---

All the process here :

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    MyClass a = MyClass(1);    // Create an object
    a = MyClass(2); // Create a temporary object and use the operator= to proceed to the copy, now a.intVar = 2
                // ^- Here the temporary object is destructed 
    return 0;
}               // a is now destructed
```

Answer (score 3):

The cout statements you've created should be considered mid-level debugging tools that are helpful for understanding what's going on under the hood of a C++ program (without actually dipping down to the low-level assembly code).  I've altered your posted code a bit in the following, replacing the compiler-generated default constructor and assignment operator with ones that operate effectively the same as the compiler-generated ones (which by themselves would be sufficient, if you weren't adding the cout statements to see what's going on under the hood)....

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {

    int myVar;

public:
    MyClass(int x) {
        myVar = x;
        std::cout << "                            constructing " << myVar << ", " << this << std::endl;
    }

    ~MyClass() {
        std::cout << "                            destructing  " << myVar << ", at " << this << std::endl;
    }

    MyClass() {
        myVar = 999;
        std::cout << "                            constructing " << myVar << ", at " << this << std::endl;
    }

    MyClass& operator=(const MyClass& rhs) {
        std::cout << "                            object " << myVar << " (at " << this <<
                ") = object " << rhs.myVar << " (at " << &rhs << ")\n";
        myVar = rhs.myVar;
        return *this;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const MyClass& m);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const MyClass& m) {
    s << m.myVar;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    MyClass a = MyClass(1);   // <---- the way you initialize 'a'
//    MyClass a(1);   //   // <---- another way to initialize 'a'
    std::cout << "Variable 'a' is now: " << a << "\n";
    std::cout << "Now setting 'a' to 2...\n";
    a = MyClass(2);
    std::cout << "Variable 'a' is now: " << a << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Coded this way, I've indented your mid-level debugging cout statements to the right, and added cout statements (that are NOT indented) to show what a programmer normally cares about if they aren't doing mid-level debugging.  When I run this, I get this:

```
                            constructing 1, 0xbfcbfb48
Variable 'a' is now: 1
Now setting 'a' to 2...
                            constructing 2, 0xbfcbfb4c
                            object 1 (at 0xbfcbfb48) = object 2 (at 0xbfcbfb4c)
                            destructing  2, at 0xbfcbfb4c
Variable 'a' is now: 2
                            destructing  2, at 0xbfcbfb48
```

What a programmer normally cares about is the stuff on the left, which is exactly what the C++ program you originally posted provides.  Note that your MyClass is storing a value, not a pointer.  Your example is coded just fine, and DOES NOT HAVE ANY BUG, if your class's data is simple values.  If your class instead contains pointers, then indeed a default constructor and assignment operator (or user-defined ones that operate like the default ones, such as the ones I show above), are no longer sufficient, because they provide shallow copies of the pointed-to data.  Your class will either need to incorporate some form of smart pointer, or else manually handle the copying of the pointed-to resource, perhaps involving reference counting for efficiency.  Some form of smart pointer is probably a safer bet.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler optimizes the first call:

```
MyClass a = MyClass(1);
```

To just one constructor call instead of a construction and then a call to the copy constructor. 
However on the second line:

```
a = MyClass(2);
```

First a temporary object is created and then it is assinged to a. Next thing that happens is that the temporary object is destroyed(thus the first `destructing 2`) and then `a` is destroyed (thus the second `destructing 2`).

The reason why `destructing 2` is printed when a is destroyed is that a default assignment operator is created for your class as you did not define one and this assignment operator will copy the value of `myVar`.

Comment: There is no "assignment" in the first case, even without any optimisation

Comment: @JonathanWakely true. The copy constructor would be called. I will fix that.

Answer (score 2):

```
MyClass a = MyClass(1);
```

This constructs an object with value 1, so you see

```
constructing 1
```

then

```
a = MyClass(2);
```

constructs a temporary object with value 2, so you see

```
constructing 2
```

the temporary object is assigned to `a`, giving `a` the same value, 2, then the temporary goes out of scope and is destroyed, so you see

```
destructing 2
```

Then at the end of `main` the variable `a` gets destroyed, and since it was re-assigned a new value you see

```
destructing 2
```

This is C++, not Java or C#, so `a` is an object not a reference. The line `a = MyClass(2);` doesn't make `a` refer to a different object, it modifies the object `a` to be a copy of the other object.

Comment: So far, this is the best explanation. But how do I keep myself from using this code that doesn't have the expected effect, when the code, not knowing the implementation of MyClass, looks like it doesn't have this odd effect? I mean, the code in main isn't making it in any way obvious that this is happening. I like to know if I can employ any simple programming rule that avoids this effect. I mean, when I read the code in main, I can't even tell that MyClass is a class and not, for instance, a function. So, by looking at main() I can't figure out that there's a bug hiding - it looks innocent!

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann, if your class have some heap objects as a members, you should consider that objects of your class can be copied, so it's just your fault that object that was copied and then destructed delete objects that are referenced by its copy

Comment: It should be obvious that `a = MyClass(2);` makes `a` take the value of `MyClass(2)`, that's how C++ works.  There is no "bug hiding", it's behaving correctly, it's only your expectation that is wrong. `MyClass` cannot be a function because you created a variable of that type.  To prevent assignment you can declare an assignment operator as `private` or (in C++11) deleted, but usually it's better to allow classes to be Assignable, so write a correct assignment operator if needed, or let the compiler do it if it's safe.

Comment: @SpongeBobFan, I'm not sure what you're trying to say but I don't think it helps here.

Answer (score 1):

When your program reaches the end of main, it destroys `a`, whose variable `myVar`'s value  at that point is 2.
If you instead write:

```
 MyClass a = MyClass(1);
 MyClass b = MyClass(2);
```

You'd see your expected output.

Comment: Not quite, that would destroy 1 and 2 twice.

Comment: Yes, what you show works but that's not answering my question

Comment: @MatsPetersson: No, it would only destroy each one once. `MyClass a = MyClass(1);` just declares and initializes `a` and is equivalent to `MyClass a(1);` and there is no copy constructor involved.

Comment: @BenjaminBannier - there **is** a copy constructor involved; if the copy constructor is not accessible the code is not valid. If the code is valid, the compiler is **allowed** to skip the copy constructor, but it is not required to. Thus, `MyClass a = MyClass(1);` can create one or two objects, and, of course, destroy however many it created.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Wouldn't you agree that in this case most often what is *allowed* is what is what is actually happening?

Comment: @BenjaminBannier It's a better idea to explain what the code, as written, *does* instead of what it optimizes to, especially to someone who's clearly new to the language and doesn't seem to understand basic principles, much less subtle things like constructor elision.

Answer (score 1):

When you say a = MyClass( 2 ); you apply the default assignment operator to the object a. In this case the value of a.myVar shall change to 2.

Instead try:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    MyClass a( 1 );
    MyClass b( 2 );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I do not need alternatives. I need to understand how I prevent my code from malfunctioning when I use the code that I did use. I need to know how I avoid making the mistake that leads to the unexpected result.